# CSS: :hover and Sibling Selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a case where my design requires me to declare this class:

```css
.panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100vh; 
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  transition-property: top;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.panel:before {
  background-color: inherit;
  top: -1.5em;
  width: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  content: attr(id);
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: none;
  border: .5em solid black;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
  border-right-color: inherit;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 25%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
}
```

In short, panels are tabs that fly in when targeted via an `<a href="panel id">foo</a>` style link.

In their default state panels sit just under the bottom of the screen, 
This creates a row of hidden panel objects whose before's appear as tabs across the bottom of the screen.

HTML for these panels is `<section id="about" class="panel color">...</section>` (where the color classes are effectively presentational for the moment, but will be upgraded to reflect specific tab purposes.

So, the challenge I'm trying to solve is that status bars will block the panel tabs which feels wrong, and I believe the solution is to bump them up a little bit (3 or 4 VH) when any link is hovered. This preserves status bar integrity, link integrity and the look of the site; treating the status bar as if it were a window resize.

I had believed that `a:hover ~ * .panel  { top: 97vh; }` was the correct solution to do this, but it doesn't seem to be firing.

Comment: Need to see your full HTML. Just showing us two separate elements doesn't tell us about the relationship between them in your markup, which is what a selector is based on.

Comment: @BoltClock, I've pushed a current version to github.
HTML: [link](https://github.com/crispen-smith/ct2/blob/master/Cinched/app/views/pages/main.html.ejs)
CSS: [link](https://github.com/crispen-smith/ct2/blob/master/Cinched/resources/stylesheets/style.css)

Comment: You seem to have a misplaced `<body>` tag in your HTML...

Comment: Dreaded copy pasta effect. I'd scaffolded this without HTML5-Reset then copied the relevant sections over.  Not a defense, just an explanation.
However, that doesn't seem to be cause of the issue as I'v resolved it and retested.   Should :hover psuedo elements be seen by ~ * .foo chains?  I've used this solution with :checked before successfully, not not with :hover.  I hadn't found a definitive call before coming here.

Comment: They should work fine because they're pseudo-classes which unlike pseudo-elements aren't affected by sibling combinators or selector chains (unless you're testing in Chrome, which is horribly broken when it comes to sibling combinators in general).

Comment: darn it.  Is there a known fix for Chrome's broken bits? I'll test in IE and Firefox to see if it's a chrome problem but I'd believed chrome to be the most trustworthy build overall.  I stand educated.

Comment: Actually, upon closer inspection of your code, I don't think it's Chrome's problem here. Keep in mind also that it's a good idea to include excerpts of your HTML that are relevant to the question here, just as you've done with your CSS.

Comment: Do you have a thought as to what the problem is?

As for the inclusion of HTML, I wasn't sure whether brevity or thoroughness was the guiding principle for questions and erred on the side of brevity.  In the future I'll be more thorough in my questions.

I've had to change to EMs instead of VHs as my other test broswers (FF, Opera, IE) didn't seem to get the heights or tops on VH... caniuse.com suggests they should be fully supported, but that's not my current experience.

FInally, thank you so much for your help on this. I'm still learning my way around stack overflow.